# What's the smartest way to copy-rename (backup) several files in different folders at once in the shell?

Tags: macos, bash, unix, backup

I want to copy-backup several files in different folder at once before updating ntpd.

Example (one file only): `sudo cp /usr/sbin/ntpd /usr/sbin/ntpd.old`

Files:

```
/usr/bin/sntp  
/usr/bin/ntp-keygen  
/usr/bin/ntpq  
/usr/sbin/ntpdc  
/usr/sbin/ntpdate  
/usr/sbin/ntpd
```

Desired result:

```
/usr/bin/sntp  
/usr/bin/sntp.old 
/usr/bin/ntp-keygen   
/usr/bin/ntp-keygen.old  
/usr/bin/ntpq  
/usr/bin/ntpq.old  
/usr/sbin/ntpdc  
/usr/sbin/ntpdc.old  
/usr/sbin/ntpdate  
/usr/sbin/ntpdate.old  
/usr/sbin/ntpd
/usr/sbin/ntpd.old
```

Does a smart one-liner exist to accomplish this task?

Answer (score 1):

Use `xargs`:

```
cat filelist | xargs -I {} cp {} {}.old
```

Comment: and how may i do this without an explicit filelist-file.

Comment: `xargs` takes lines from standard input to build and run commands. You can run `xargs -I {} cp {} {}.old`, input filenames (on separate lines) by hand (or via paste) and press Ctrl+D (marks end of input).

Comment: There's a useless use of `cat`, and the preferred way to pipe to `xargs` (if even needed) is to use `find … -print0 | xargs -0`.

Answer (score 1):

#### Using a shell loop

Something like a simple loop, iterating over two directories and then matching files:

```
for dir in /usr/bin /usr/sbin; do
  for file in "$dir/"*ntp*; do 
    sudo cp "$dir/$file" "$dir/$file.old"
  done 
done
```

This will copy all files matching the `*ntp*` pattern in both directories to the same file name, with `.old` appended.

Make sure to quote the variables correctly as a safeguard against files with whitespace in their name. The pattern `*ntp*` must not be quoted so that it can be expanded.

#### Using `find`

You could use `find` and `-exec` too:

```
find /usr/bin /usr/sbin -type f -iname '*ntp*' -exec sudo cp {} {}.old \;
```

The above would be safer since it only runs on files – but you're not expecting to have directories called `ntp`, so that's fine, I suppose.